# Insufficient argument in Conway's Proof of Krein Milman

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

In the proof of Krein-Milman in *A course in functional analysis* by John B. Conway p.142. The following argument is used:

$K$ is a compact convex set in a locally convex space $X$ and $U\subset K$ is a proper convex subset which is open with respect to the subspace topology inherited from $K$. Then in the proof it is claimed that if $x\in U$ and $y\in \overline{U}\setminus U$ then the open line segment from  $x$ to $y$ is contained in $U$: that is $(1-t)x+ty\in U$ for $0< t <1$.

However this is not true for any situation. For instance if $K = [-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ and $U = (-1,1)\times (-1,1)\cup (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\times \{1\}$ then $y =(1,1)\in \overline{U}\setminus U$ and $x=(0,1)\in U$ however $(1-t)x+ty\notin U$ for $1/2\leq t<1$.

[image]

Can the property that $U$ is a maximal proper open subset of $K$ be used to get around this fact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're right, this is a gap in Conway's proof.  The problem seems to be that he applies Proposition IV.1.11, which would require $x$ to be an interior point of $U$ (with respect to the ambient topology of $X$); this would be valid if $U$ were open in $X$, but here it is only relatively open in $K$.  This error doesn't appear in [the errata list on his web page](https://home.gwu.edu/~conway/), so you might like to let him know about it.

To fix his proof, let's follow his notation and let $T_{x,\lambda}(y) = \lambda y + (1-\lambda) x$ for $x,y \in K$ and $0 \le \lambda < 1$.  For $x \in U$, the set $T^{-1}_{x,\lambda}(U)$ is a relatively open convex subset of $K$ that contains $U$, so by maximality it is either $K$ or $U$.

We want to show it is $K$.  Suppose not; then there exists $y \in K$ with $T_{x,\lambda}(y) \notin U$.  Then we can find some other point $z$ on the line joining $x,y$ such that $z \notin U$ but $T_{x,\lambda}(z) \in U$.  For example, you could set $z_0 = y$, $z_{n+1} = T_{x,\lambda}(z_n)$.  Then $z_n \to x$, and so since $U$ is relatively open, we have $z_n \in U$ for sufficiently large $n$.  Now let $z = z_k$ with the greatest $k$ such that $z_k \notin U$.  This would show $T_{x,\lambda}^{-1}(U) \ne U$, contrary to our assumption.

Intuitively, the idea is that if the open line from $x$ to $y$ were not contained in $U$, we could dilate the set $U$ outward from $x$, just enough to make it contain some additional points of the line but still exclude $y$.  That would produce a larger convex relatively open proper subset of $K$.

Comment: This was a very nice solution. Thanks! However, don't you need that $0\leq \lambda <1$? Since otherwise $T_{x,\lambda}(y) = y$ for every $y$.

Comment: @Olof: Thanks, corrected.